# How does this code cause a -100 error in ghostscript

Tags: vb.net, ghostscript

I'm using the GhostScript.NET.Processor dll to send a pdf to print from a web service. The code I'm trying to execute is:

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(Sub()

       Dim inputFile As String = "C:\WebServiceLog\checklist.pdf"
       Dim printerName As String = "MIAUMIAUMIAU"
       Using processor As New GhostscriptProcessor()
            Dim switches As New List(Of String)()
            switches.Add("-empty")
            switches.Add("-dPrinted")
            switches.Add("-dBATCH")
            switches.Add("-dNOPAUSE")
            switches.Add("-dNOSAFER")
            switches.Add("-dDuplex")
            switches.Add("-dTumble=0")
            switches.Add("-dNumCopies=1")
            switches.Add("-sDEVICE=mswinpr2")
            switches.Add(Convert.ToString("-sOutputFile=%printer%") & printerName)
            switches.Add("-f")
            switches.Add(inputFile)
            processor.StartProcessing(switches.ToArray(), Nothing)
         End Using
 End Sub)
```

The error that I keep getting is 
***An error occured when call to 'gsapi_new_instance' is made: -100***
 I am running 64bit. Any help on this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is causing Ghostscript to return an error of -100?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4340407/what-is-causing-ghostscript-to-return-an-error-of-100)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For future reference. It was IIS permissions. After I changed these to an account that had access to the printer everything worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

-empty isn't a Ghostscript option (though it might be something to do with the .NET code, I wouldn't know).

The first thing I would do is try using Ghostscript from the command line with the exact same command line arguments, I would suggest this is more likely to tell you if anything is wrong. You should also check if Ghostscript sent anything to stderr or stdout (it almost certainly **will** have sent something, and you haven't quoted the output)

If that does fail, simplify the command line by either removing arguments one at a time until it works, or by reducing to the minimum and adding one at a time until it doesn't.

Note that many of the options you are supplying (eg -dTumble and -dDuplex) will have no effect whatever with the mswinpr2 device.